# Phase portrait of the pendulum

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Lets consider the system of differential equation:

$$\phi'(t)=\psi(t)$$
$$\psi'(t)=-\sin(\phi(t))$$

How one can get the corresponding phase portrait? For example I found [this](http://images.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fmathworld.wolfram.com%2Fimages%2Feps-gif%2FPhasePortrait_900.gif&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fmathworld.wolfram.com%2FPhasePortrait.html&h=167&w=567&tbnid=V68qIpClCDnkEM%3A&docid=WGuEzQ8XQeOTUM&ei=ukOfVs7wLoasa5qqtuAE&tbm=isch&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=212&page=1&start=0&ndsp=9&ved=0ahUKEwjOteL5-rfKAhUG1hoKHRqVDUwQrQMIITAA) one but I dont know how to get it.

Is it possible to get it without solving the differential equation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no need to solve the equation. Simply find an integral.

Answer (score 2):

The second order equation is 
$$
ϕ''+\sinϕ=0
$$
Multiply with $ϕ'$ and integrate to get
$$
\frac12ϕ'^2 - \cos ϕ=C
$$
Which means that the trajectories of the ODE lie inside the level surfaces of
$$
E(ϕ,ψ)=\frac12ψ^2 +(1-\cos ϕ)
$$
(modified to have both terms positive, $1-\cos ϕ=2\sin^2(ϕ/2)$.) Use contour plots to transform this first integral into a phase portrait.